How Do I Turn Off or Delete Copilot on Windows 10?
How do I turn off or delete Copilot on Windows 10? Please note: Windows 10, the latest update 9th October 2024.
It appeared today in the Taskbar after an update.
It is not just within Edge, it is an actual program on the taskbar.
Copilot Version 0.4.2.0.
I have looked in Setting|Personalisation|Taskbar and nothing is there.
I have Googled this and nothing works or it is exclusively for Windows 11.
It is not in Control Panel|Apps|Uninstall

@Ramhound they state that they have this on Windows 10.

Microsoft transitioned Copilot into sort-of a PWA, so you can just unpin it from the taskbar.
If you don't want it, you can also turn off Copilot via policies.
Source.
Pro Edition

Go to  User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows
Components > Windows Copilot
Click the Turn off Windows Copilot GPO.
Click Enabled  then OK.

Home Edition

Press Win + R and type regedit in the Run box.
Navigate to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows key.
Right-click the Windows key in the left, and select New > Key from the menu.
Type WindowsCopilot for the new key name and hit Enter
Now, right-click the WindowsCopilot key you just created and select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value from its right-click menu.
Name the new value TurnOffWindowsCopilot and double-click it to change its value data.
Set its value to 1.
Sign out + sign in to apply the change. (or restarting, whatever works for you)


Can the person who downvoted this answer explain why? I do not want to try this if it is dangerous, or something Joe Average should not be trying. This seems a reasonably well thought out answer.
